# My.Computer is Not A Member of.... Issue Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio Community Addition. I've learned a lot of Visual Basic over the past couple of years using Windows Application Forms -- I'm self taught so sorry if that's not their 'official' name. Anyway, moving onto Windows 10's app development, I've noticed a lot of changes take place where my code simply needs changed a lot to work. Am I missing something big here? I only want to create Windows Store apps for desktop at the moment and using the Visual Studio language I expected much of my code to work as is.

Here's an example of some code I expected tor work:

```
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(txtDir.Text)
```

Returns this error highlighting `My.Computer`

> Error BC30456 'Computer' is not a member of 'App3'.

Sorry if this is something simple, as I say, I'm self taught have been unable to find a solution online. I expect a lot of people will have the same problem as me at some point as well, so hence why I thought it would be worth a thread.

Comment: It looks like name space problem. Have you tried Googling the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application framework (which gives you all the stuff under the `My` namespace is incompatible with Windows Store apps, which only support a subset of the .Net API. The closest equivalent would be the sample for [Enumerate files and folders in a location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt185400.aspx):

```vb
Dim picturesFolder As StorageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary ' Although you probably want to get the StorageFolder for the directory specified by txtDir.Text here instead
Dim outputText As New StringBuilder

Dim fileList As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFile) =
    Await picturesFolder.GetFilesAsync()

outputText.AppendLine("Files:")
For Each file As StorageFile In fileList

    outputText.Append(file.Name & vbLf)

Next file

Dim folderList As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFolder) =
    Await picturesFolder.GetFoldersAsync()

outputText.AppendLine("Folders:")
For Each folder As StorageFolder In folderList

    outputText.Append(folder.DisplayName & vbLf)

Next folder
```